# Получение графического текста (данных) из окна стороннего приложения

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

Задача в том, чтобы получать данные из стороннего приложения и взаимодействовать с ним. Для начала инжект в приложение, затем хук функций через Detours чтобы получать текст клиента приложения, и работать с данными.

Затем необходимо открывать дополнительное окно, где графика прорисовывается через OpenGL.
Вот здесь у меня ступор. С этого окна так же необходимо получить ники игроков - это текст(но он уже графический) и колонки, которые находятся всегда в одной позиции(так же графика). Через WinAPI и т.п. не получится, ибо это не просто текст окна.

Было несколько вариантов.
1. Каждый раз делать скриншот, затем пытаться его распознать - проблемно. Т.к. шрифт искажается при увеличении размера экрана, оно может быть любым, а нужно получать с точностью до буквы. Я пытался делать чернобелые скриншоты, но то символ какой-то косячный, то залезет на границу рисунка, то еще что. Даже шрифт идеально подбирал.
2. Получать данные из памяти приложения, но и здесь не все так просто, полный бардак, они приходят туда в HTML виде, в разброс и как будто зашифровано.
3. И вариант еще сложнее, но думаю почти нереальный - это работа с видеодрайвером напрямую.

Нужна подсказка знающих людей или хотя бы направление, куда копать. Потерял уже с этим почти 3 недели времени.

Comment: Вы работаете с окном какой то игры и хотите извлечь из него текстовые данные? Но как представлены эти данные? Может быть легче посмотреть в каких элементах UI хранятся данные (например, через UISpy), а затем уже работать с этими элементами через PostMessage?

Comment: @D.Stark да, с окном игры. Я хукал все методы TextOut, но это работает для половины того, что мне нужно. А в отдельном окне (другое окно игры) это не подходит, там другой метод вывода. Текст не распознается...
Использовал программу apimonitor, она не зафиксировала вывода текста, соответственно вывод происходит через стороннюю библиотеку графики. Через spy++ пытался, ничего..

Comment: Т.е. текст рисуется на картинке? Может быть тогда следует сделать хук на вызов функций типа DrawText?

Comment: Назовите визуальное дерево элементов, в котором находится нужный элемент (в котором текст находится).

Comment: @D.Stark, в игре используется DrawTextW, который отображает список всех игр, но когда открыть что-либо из списка он не используется в новом окне. Там текст рисуется на картинке, скорее всего через OpenGL или похожее.

Comment: Т.е. при нажатии на какой то элемент меню у вас открывается новое окно, где есть некоторый элемент, содержащий картинку, на которой, как вы предполагаете, средствами OpenGL рисуется нужный вам текст?

Comment: Если да, назовите тип и родителей нужного элемента